# EventStore ClientAPI Subscription issue

Tags: c#, cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I am facing a subscription issue with EventStore.ClientAPI. I have a projection manager that configured to subscribe all and the service started and i am getting subscriptions for events such as $metadata, $UserCreated, $statsCollected etc. but no event from the stream i created. I am pretty new here, please guide me where i am going wrong.

```
void InitiateProjection(IProjection projection)
        {
            var checkpoint = GetCurrentPosition(projection.GetType());

            _eventStoreConnection.SubscribeToAllFrom(
                checkpoint,
                CatchUpSubscriptionSettings.Default,
                EventAppeared(projection),
                LiveProcessingStarted(projection));
        }
```

Event store - product created event

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you specifically connect to ProductCreatedDomainEvent+d78435fc43fd-a7bf-56c01d7efa25?

As an observation, the stream name might start to give you problems (unless you changed the system proejctions to search for + instead or - already?)

If you have changed to +, could you try conencting to the $ce-ProductCreatedDomainEvent and see what you get.

Comment: Hi @steven-blair, the subscription was fine, there was a problem with my handler and that was skipped. Anyway thanks for looking into. Now I am facing another problem, I don't know if there any reliable pattern to solve this problem. The new problem is - Idempotency in event handlers. Store publish event multiple times, i assume it's normal, but i need to find a way to handle that only once. please let me know if you have any thought around it.

Comment: @VibinKesavan you got another question, so please post it as a separate question.